# Как определить какая сущность должна содержать ссылку на другую в БД

Tags: java, hibernate, java-8

Есть две сущности: `User` и `Address`. Они в моем случае должны быть связаны связью один-к-одному, то есть в одной из них должна быть ссылка на другую: либо в классе `User` должно быть поле `Address address`, к которому мы пишем `@JoinColumn`, а со стороны адреса делаем `mappedBy`, либо же в классе `Address` поле `User user` и проделываем то же самое. Так вот, как именно определить, какая сущность при односторонней связи является как бы явно зависимой от другой, а какая не должна знать о своей связи с ней?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы пишите:

> Они в моем случае должны быть связаны связью один-к-одному, то есть в одной из них должна быть ссылка на другую

, а затем:

> либо в классе User должно быть поле Address address, к которому мы пишем @JoinColumn, а со стороны адреса делаем mappedBy

Это уже двунаправленное отображение (bidirectional).

> Так вот, как именно определить, какая сущность при односторонней связи является как бы явно зависимой от другой, а какая не должна знать о своей связи с ней?

Возможный способ отображения связи *один-к-одному* с помощью внешнего ключа:

Address:

```
@Entity
class Address { /* impl */ }
```

User:

```
@Entity
class User
{
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(unique = true)
    protected Address homeAddress;
}
```

Разумеется, это не полное определение классов-сущностей, я указал только важные в данном контексте детали.

Пример использования:

```
var user = new User("...");
var addr = new Address("...");
user.setHomeAddress(addr);
em.persist(user);
```

Сохранение `addr` произошло транзитивно при сохрании `user`.

Так вот, при одностороннем отображении мы не "трогаем" вторую сущность (заметьте отсутствие аннотаций в классе Address), соответственно не возникает вопроса, вроде, "где писать mappedBy".

Comment: Да, действительно сработало. Просто во всех примерах, которые я видел, в одном классе был JoinColumn, а в другом mappedBy. Но оказывается можно и без mappedBy

Comment: @NarasuOo, рад помочь! :)

Answer (score -1):

Обе таблицы должны иметь поля для ссылок друг на друга, если заранее неизвестно за какой конец этого relation будут дергать БД.

Comment: К первой части вашего сообшения -- не совсем понятно, как это отвечает на вопрос в этом топике. Не могли бы вы пояснить более подробно?

Comment: Ко второй части вашего сообшения -- если вы считаете, что удалённый вопрос интересен, то просто задайте его от своего лица и дайте на него самоответ. Это допустимо и даже приветствуется. Во избежание разочарованиия и потереного времени, пройдите для начала [Тур](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour), чтобы понять, что такое "хороший вопрос" и как на него хорошо ответить.

Comment: @0xdb : Спасибо за ссылку на "Тур" - я действительно только сегодня стал пользователем этого сайта, а движок здесь непривычный. Тур наверняка пригодится, но не в данной конкретной ситуации. Что до "переиздания" вопроса от своего лица, то ведь тогда ответ не будет увиден автором вопроса, а хотелось именно человеку помочь. Да и не сохранились у меня нужные детали его вопроса (там картинка была с таблицами).

Comment: @0xdb : _Не могли бы вы пояснить более подробно?_ Простите, не сразу заметил предыдущий пост - смотрел на последний. Приведу пример - можно найти адрес человека и обратиться в таблицу Юзеров с к.л. редактированием, а можно наоборот - найти Юзера, а потом обратиться в таблицу Адресов с к.л. другим редактированием (или просто просмотром - какая разница?)

Comment: В данной конкретной ситуации трудно что-то посоветовать, так как удалённого вопроса я тоже не вижу. А в общем: 1) если автор удалил вопрос, значит его решение для него по какой то причине больше не актуально, вы вряд ли чем-то ему поможете 2) создав свой вопрос с самответом вы поможете сотням (или даже тысячам) других, которые найдут решение через поисковик (именно на это ориентирован данный ресурс)  PS я ориентировался на то, что раз вы потратили время на создание примера с решением, то у вас достаточно данных, чтобы воссоздать самому удалённый вопрос.

Comment: Так ведь случай-то был сформулирован достаточно частный и конкретный. Врядли у кого-то возникнет именно такой вопрос. Я ответил здесь лишь затем, чтобы автор знал, что ему дали (подготовили) ответ. А удалить вопрос он мог как непреднамеренно (кнопочки рядом), так и по причине переноса его, скажем, на SQL.ru

Comment: “В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша репутация достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению; на данный момент, пожалуйста, внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора.”